# Script to Tar file in a specific Directory

Tags: scripting, tar, compression

I'm trying to write a Unix script that will go to a specific directory and tar.gz all the log files that are older than 2 days.  So far I have this but it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

AGE_TO_COMPRESS="2419200" # 172800 seconds = 2 days
LOG_FILES="/myfile/logs"

for file in $LOG_FILES;
do
  if [ $(( `date +%s`)) -gt ${AGE_TO_COMPRESS} ]
     then
        tar -cvzf $file.tar.gz $file;
     fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Note that the script you provided does several things weirdly, for example it never checks file times at all, and looks like it may attempt to tar a single file. If the answer is not helpful because we misunderstood your requirements, please explain them in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected most evident errors of your script. 
I supposed that `LOG_FILES` will contain a list of files to compress.

```
#!/bin/bash

AGE_TO_COMPRESS=2419200 # 28 days

# list of file to compress
LOG_FILES="/tmp/test/test /tmp/test/test2 /tmp/test/test3 /tmp/test/test4"

# Any file older than EDGE_DATE must be compressed
NOW=$( date +%s )
EDGE_DATE=$(( NOW - AGE_TO_COMPRESS ))

for file in $LOG_FILES ; do
    # check if file exists
    if [ -e "$file" ] ; then 

        # compare "modified date" of file to EDGE_DATE
        if [ $( stat -c %Y "$file" ) -lt ${EDGE_DATE} ] ; then

            # create tar file of a single file
            # this is an odd way to compress a file
            tar -cvzf $file.tar.gz $file

            # do we want to delete the old file?
            # rm "$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

In any case, I agree with @dhag that a `find`/`bzip2` solution would be better.

Have you taken in account to use `logrotate`? Why do you want to rewrite the wheel when dedicated software exists?

Comment: Note that using a variable to store a list of filenames is a poor solution. E.g. you cannot have file with spaces in its name.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to scripting. I tried the code you've provided but it doesn't work.

Comment: Obviously, you have to adapt the code to your needs. My answer is only an explanation of your errors, an example to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The command `find -type f -mtime +2` will find files older than two
days. You can then use find's option `-exec` to compress them; perhaps
like this:

```
find -type f -mtime +2 -exec gzip {} +
```

If you know extra things about the file, perhaps that their names all
end in `.log`, it may be wise to add this to your filter (`-name
'*.log'`).